# mod_security gives "Multipart parser detected a possible unmatched boundary" for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache2, mod-security

I have mod_security (apache2) installed on my server hosting Wordpress websites. When I attempt to install a plugin by uploading a .zip file from the disk it fails with 403 Forbidden and "Multipart parser detected a possible unmatched boundary" in the log. In my configuration this rule is defined in /etc/modsecurity/modsecurity.conf line 82, rule #200003. I've attempted to disable it in REQUEST-900-EXCLUSION-RULES-BEFORE-CRS.conf, but it isn't working.

Is it safe to disable it in /etc/modsecurity/modsecurity.conf?
Why the rule exclusion isn't working?

Comment: Check here for a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31659316/apache-error-500-on-large-file-uploads-mod-security (adding `SecRuleRemoveById 200003` to the bottom of mod_security.conf may fix the issue). Restart Apache after.